# Error creating invoice error description 'This entry already exists in the following tables

Tags: c#, sapb1

We use SAP Business One SDK and I am creating and invoice and it is working fine for 90 percent of the customers however the appears to be an issue with cash sales account as they use the same account code each time. Now the issue is that it is saying the description of the invoice is the same and therefore the item already exists in the invoice table.

Obv I am using a stock code for the item that is going in but can someone tell me what is going wrong here surely and invoice can have the same description of an item to a customer?

The description is brought in via the stock ecode which we pass to the function.

```
public string ProcessInvoice(out int errorCode, out string errorDescription, out int isProcessed, List<FuelPumpData> _unprocessedInvocies)
    {
        errorCode = 0;
        isProcessed = 0;
        errorDescription = "";


        try
        {
            decimal _pricePerLitre = GetPricePerLitre();
            SAPbobsCOM.Documents oInvoice = company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oInvoices);
            foreach (FuelPumpData _invoice in _unprocessedInvocies)
            { 
                
                oInvoice.DocDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_invoice.Date);
                oInvoice.CardCode = _invoice.CardCode;
                
                oInvoice.Lines.ItemCode = _invoice.FuelType;
                oInvoice.Lines.Quantity = (double)_invoice.FuelQty;
                oInvoice.Lines.PriceAfterVAT = (double)_pricePerLitre;
                oInvoice.Lines.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_TransTime").Value = _invoice.Time.ToString();
                oInvoice.Lines.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_KeyFob").Value = _invoice.KeyFob;


                oInvoice.Lines.Add();
                int addInvoice = oInvoice.Add();
                string docNo = company.GetNewObjectKey();
                if (addInvoice < 0)
                {
                    string errordescription = company.GetLastErrorDescription();
                    errorCode = company.GetLastErrorCode();
                    errorDescription = company.GetLastErrorDescription();
                    isProcessed = 0;
                    Console.Write("Error:" + company.GetLastErrorDescription());
                    UpdateProcessedFlag(_invoice.Code, (int)ImportErrorEnum.ErrorOccoured, docNo);//will change this to enum
                    log.Error(string.Format("Error creating invoice error description {0} {1} ", company.GetLastErrorDescription(), company.GetLastErrorDescription()));
                }
                else
                {
                    company.GetNewObjectCode(out docCode);
                    UpdateProcessedFlag(_invoice.Code, (int)ImportErrorEnum.Processed, docNo);//will change this to enum
                    log.Info("Invoice Created for " + _invoice.CardCode.ToString() + " Customer Name" + _invoice.CustomerName + " Transaction Time Of " + _invoice.Time);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorCode = company.GetLastErrorCode();
            errorDescription = company.GetLastErrorDescription();
            log.Error(string.Format("Error creating invoice error description {0} {1} .net error {2} ", company.GetLastErrorDescription(), company.GetLastErrorDescription(), ex.StackTrace.ToString()));
        }
        return docCode;
    }
```

I am using the SDK to right to SAP and not ODBC. This is the exact error I am getting:

> 2019-01-18 17:46:37.0972 - ERROR: Error creating invoice error
> description [INV1.WhsCode][line: 1] , 'This entry already exists in
> the following tables (ODBC -2035)' [INV1.WhsCode][line: 1] , 'This
> entry already exists in the following tables (ODBC -2035)'

Comment: Seems to be ODBC error, SAP never throws such errors

Comment: Agreed the porogram has work 100% it was when other developers removing and droping stuff when they should not have been this was correct what you said.  I dont use odbc to com with sap just the sdk which i thought was strange.